# After upgrading to Rails 3.2 my rake tasks are broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

After upgrading to Rails 3.2 my rake tasks can't autoload models anymore.

The following was working in rails 3.1:

```
09:04:14 /srv/www/gamersmafia/current$ rake --trace gm:update_default_skin_styles
rake aborted!                                                                   
No such file to load -- notification                                            
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `eager_load!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each' 
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `eager_load!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each' 
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
/srv/www/gamersmafia/current/lib/tasks/update_games_and_factions_sprite.rake:1
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `load_tasks'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `each' 
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `load_tasks'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:145:in `load_tasks'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/srv/www/gamersmafia/current/Rakefile:7                                         
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `run' 
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run' 
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33                            
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'                                                
/usr/local/bin/rake:19
```

The code for my app is open sourced so you can check it here:

```
https://github.com/slnc/gamersmafia
```

The only modification I have done is to add a

"Rails.application.eager_load!" line to the beginning of the rake task shown above. Without it it wouldn't load the "Skins" library.

UPDATE
I tried debugging this by adding puts statements on each line of the stack trace shown above and I can see something like this:

```
eager_load_path: /srv/www/gamersmafia/current/app/mailers
file found: /srv/www/gamersmafia/current/app/mailers/notification.rb
require_dependency notification
... notification
rake aborted!
```

Which roughly seems to indicate that rails is finding the notification.rb file but when it tries to load it it can't.

Comment: It looks like it's not related to Rails 3.2. I went back to Rails 3.1 and it's also failing. I have recently done a lot of refactorings moving code out of vendor/plugins and into config/initializers and that might be the reason it's failing now.

Comment: The strange thing is that I have to add a "Rails.application.eager_load!" line. My understanding was that adding an :environment param to the task would force rails to load.

Answer (score 0):

```
gem install notification
```

Might just do the trick, seeing as `No such file to load -- notification` indicates a failure in a `require 'notification'`.

Comment: Thanks solo but that doesn't seem to work. I do have a model called "notification", it's in the app/mailers dir.